# Cookie String in Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, webview

I tried to fetch cookies from a given url using normal flutter webview. But, I couldn't find any standard method for the same.
How to get a cookie string from a given url in Flutter WebView?

Answer (score 6):

**Official version WebView** 
You need to use `controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');` 
code snippet

```
void _onListCookies(
    WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
  final String cookies =
      await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text('Cookies:'),
        _getCookieList(cookies),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

full detail http://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/03/28/webview-in-flutter-part-2/ 
full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

const String examplepage = '''
      <!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
      <body>
      <p>
      The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
      </p>
      <ul>
      <ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
      </ul>
      </body>
      </html>
      ''';

class WebviewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  WebviewDemo({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WebviewDemoState();
  }
}

JavascriptChannel snackbarJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
  return JavascriptChannel(
    name: 'SnackbarJSChannel',
    onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message.message),
      ));
    },
  );
}

class _WebviewDemoState extends State<WebviewDemo> {
  //
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Webview Demo'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          SampleMenu(_controller.future)
        ],
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: 'http://flutter.dev',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              snackbarJavascriptChannel(context),
            ].toSet(),
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com")) {
                print("Blocking navigation");
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum MenuOptions {
  showUserAgent,
  listCookies,
  clearCookies,
  addToCache,
  listCache,
  clearCache,
  navigationDelegate
}

class SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleMenu(this.controller);
  final Future<WebViewController> controller;
  final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: controller,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.showUserAgent,
                  child: const Text('Show User Agent'),
                  enabled: controller.hasData,
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.listCookies,
                  child: const Text('List Cookies'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.clearCookies,
                  child: const Text('Clear Cookies'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.addToCache,
                  child: const Text('Add to Cache'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.listCache,
                  child: const Text('List Cache'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.clearCache,
                  child: const Text('Clear Cache'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: MenuOptions.navigationDelegate,
                  child: const Text('Navigation Delegate Demo'),
                )
              ],
          onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
            switch (value) {
              case MenuOptions.showUserAgent:
                showUserAgent(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCookies:
                listCookies(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCookies:
                clearCookies(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.addToCache:
                addToCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCache:
                listCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCache:
                clearCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.navigationDelegate:
                navigationDelegateDemo(controller.data, context);
                break;
              default:
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  navigationDelegateDemo(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentbase64 =
        base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(examplepage));
    controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentbase64');
  }

  addToCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Added a test entry to cache'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void listCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.keys().then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys": cacheKeys, "localStorage": localStorage })).then((caches) => SnackbarJSChannel.postMessage(caches))');
  }

  void clearCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.clearCache();
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Cache Cleared'),
      ),
    );
  }

  listCookies(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies =
        await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[const Text('Cookies:'), getCookies(cookies)],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getCookies(String cookies) {
    if (null == cookies || cookies.isEmpty) {
      return Container();
    }
    final List<String> cookieList = cookies.split(';');
    final Iterable<Text> cookieWidgets = cookieList.map(
      (String cookie) => Text(cookie),
    );
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: cookieWidgets.toList(),
    );
  }

  void clearCookies(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();
    String message = 'There are no cookies';
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }

  showUserAgent(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'SnackbarJSChannel.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);');
  }
}

class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture);
  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                      if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                        controller.goBack();
                      } else {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                            content: Text("No Back history Item"),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                      if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                        controller.goForward();
                      } else {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                            content: Text("No Forward history Item"),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                      controller.reload();
                    },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Community version WebView** 
You can use https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

code snippet

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                flutterWebViewPlugin.getCookies().then((m) {
                  setState(() {
                    _history.add('cookies: $m');
                  });
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Cookies'),
            )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

const kAndroidUserAgent =
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36';

String selectedUrl = 'https://flutter.io';

// ignore: prefer_collection_literals
final Set<JavascriptChannel> jsChannels = [
  JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Print',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print(message.message);
      }),
].toSet();

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter WebView Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter WebView Demo'),
        '/widget': (_) {
          return WebviewScaffold(
            url: selectedUrl,
            javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Widget WebView'),
            ),
            withZoom: true,
            withLocalStorage: true,
            hidden: true,
            initialChild: Container(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text('Waiting.....'),
              ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    onPressed: () {
                      flutterWebViewPlugin.goBack();
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    onPressed: () {
                      flutterWebViewPlugin.goForward();
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.autorenew),
                    onPressed: () {
                      flutterWebViewPlugin.reload();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Instance of WebView plugin
  final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  // On destroy stream
  StreamSubscription _onDestroy;

  // On urlChanged stream
  StreamSubscription<String> _onUrlChanged;

  // On urlChanged stream
  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;

  StreamSubscription<WebViewHttpError> _onHttpError;

  StreamSubscription<double> _onProgressChanged;

  StreamSubscription<double> _onScrollYChanged;

  StreamSubscription<double> _onScrollXChanged;

  final _urlCtrl = TextEditingController(text: selectedUrl);

  final _codeCtrl = TextEditingController(text: 'window.navigator.userAgent');

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final _history = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.close();

    _urlCtrl.addListener(() {
      selectedUrl = _urlCtrl.text;
    });

    // Add a listener to on destroy WebView, so you can make came actions.
    _onDestroy = flutterWebViewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        // Actions like show a info toast.
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: const Text('Webview Destroyed')));
      }
    });

    // Add a listener to on url changed
    _onUrlChanged = flutterWebViewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('onUrlChanged: $url');
        });
      }
    });

    _onProgressChanged =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((double progress) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('onProgressChanged: $progress');
        });
      }
    });

    _onScrollYChanged =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onScrollYChanged.listen((double y) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('Scroll in Y Direction: $y');
        });
      }
    });

    _onScrollXChanged =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onScrollXChanged.listen((double x) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('Scroll in X Direction: $x');
        });
      }
    });

    _onStateChanged =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('onStateChanged: ${state.type} ${state.url}');
        });
      }
    });

    _onHttpError =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onHttpError.listen((WebViewHttpError error) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add('onHttpError: ${error.code} ${error.url}');
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Every listener should be canceled, the same should be done with this stream.
    _onDestroy.cancel();
    _onUrlChanged.cancel();
    _onStateChanged.cancel();
    _onHttpError.cancel();
    _onProgressChanged.cancel();
    _onScrollXChanged.cancel();
    _onScrollYChanged.cancel();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: TextField(controller: _urlCtrl),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(
                  selectedUrl,
                  rect: Rect.fromLTWH(
                      0.0, 0.0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 300.0),
                  userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,
                  invalidUrlRegex:
                      r'^(https).+(twitter)', // prevent redirecting to twitter when user click on its icon in flutter website
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Open Webview (rect)'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(selectedUrl, hidden: true);
              },
              child: const Text('Open "hidden" Webview'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(selectedUrl);
              },
              child: const Text('Open Fullscreen Webview'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget');
              },
              child: const Text('Open widget webview'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: TextField(controller: _codeCtrl),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final future =
                    flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript(_codeCtrl.text);
                future.then((String result) {
                  setState(() {
                    _history.add('eval: $result');
                  });
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Eval some javascript'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _history.clear();
                });
                flutterWebViewPlugin.close();
              },
              child: const Text('Close'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                flutterWebViewPlugin.getCookies().then((m) {
                  setState(() {
                    _history.add('cookies: $m');
                  });
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Cookies'),
            ),
            Text(_history.join('\n'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thx @chunhunghan!. I will try the above and get back to you if any issues.

Comment: Fails if the cookie has http only to be true. since JavaScript cant access those cookies

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Cookie with flutter_webview, now you can use
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager

Comment: This plugin works fine with higher Android sdks but didn't work with Marshmallow.

Answer (score 3):

The `webview_flutter` plugin doesn't offer a method to get the cookies using its `CookieManager`.
Instead, you can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

It also implements a `CookieManager` for both Android and iOS platforms!
To get the cookies, simply use `CookieManager.instance().getCookies(url: url);`

Here is an example that prints the list of all cookies for that URL when the WebView stops loading:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;
  CookieManager _cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://github.com/flutter",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      _webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                      List<Cookie> cookies = await _cookieManager.getCookies(url: url);
                      cookies.forEach((cookie) {
                        print(cookie.name + " " + cookie.value);
                      });
                    },
                  ))
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, did this packages saves all the cookies from the loaded url ?

Comment: This package worked fine for Oreo and higher versions. Somehow, it's not working for Marshmallow :/. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have any problem, please post an issue with example code on the issue section of the GitHub repo please.