# How to store user cookie on WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using a webview to display Wordpress login page in my flutter app but when ever a user press back button, they always have to login back to their accounts so I'm just wondering how can I save their user login information in the cookie so that they don't have to login again after they use webview?

I'm using webview_flutter: ^2.0.4.

MyWebView Screen.

```
            Expanded(
                child: Center(
              child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://chinblog.com/wp-login.php",
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  }),
            ))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie String in Flutter WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733001/cookie-string-in-flutter-webview)

Answer (score 0):

It is a duplicate of [59733001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733001/cookie-string-in-flutter-webview). You can check the link and use webview cookie manager or you can get cookie from javascript channel in webview.