# How to accept third party cookies on flutter webview

Tags: flutter, cookies, webview

I converted my website to an app using flutter, the website has a login page which stores users credentials via cookie, however, the cookies is not being set in the flutter webview app.

In Java, I would do:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true)
```

Please, is there an alternative for this in flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie String in Flutter WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733001/cookie-string-in-flutter-webview)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to third party cookie from my website unto the flutter app so that users don't keep logging in whenever they open the app.